# Disables Crosshair for one series of two

Tags: highcharts

I'm using a chart with two series as you can see in http://jsfiddle.net/Charissima/zo5j94qz/4/

Is it possible to disable crosshairs for the second series? The problem is, that when the moise pointer is near the black series s2, there is no crosshair for the blue series s1 and I don't need/want crosshairs for the black series but for the blue.

```
        var myData = [];
        for (var i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
            myData.push([i, i + Math.random() * 3]);
        }
        var myDataLine = [];
        myDataLine.push([0,6]);
        myDataLine.push([23,6]);

        chart = $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart : {
                zoomType: 'x',
            },
            series: [{
                name: 's1',
                data: myData,
                type: 'line'
            },{
                name: 's2',
                data: myDataLine,
                type: 'line'
            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defaulty it is not built-in, but you can prepare your own crosshair function like in the example:

```
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        var chart = this.series.chart,
                            r = chart.renderer,
                            left = chart.plotLeft,
                            top = chart.plotTop,
                            width = chart.plotWidth,
                            height = chart.plotHeight,
                            x = this.plotX,
                            y = this.plotY;

                        if (this.series.options.enabledCrosshairs) {
                            crosshair = r.path(['M', left, top + y, 'L', left + width, top + y, 'M', left + x, top, 'L', left + x, top + height])
                                .attr({
                                'stroke-width': 1,
                                stroke: 'red'
                            })
                                .add();
                        }
                    },
                    mouseOut: function () {
                        if (crosshair.d !== UNDEFINED) crosshair.destroy();
                    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u4ha3cxw/7/

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, this is very possible**. Use 2 [x-axes](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis), one with crosshair's enabled and the other with crosshairs disabled. Then specify which series you would like to use which axis:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: [{
    crosshair: {
      enabled: true,
      width: 5
    }
  }, {
    crosshair: false,
    visible: false
  }],

  series: [{
      name: 'Series w/ Crosshair',
      xAxis: 0, // You could omit this, highcharts uses the first axis in array by default
      data: [99.9, 81.5, 76.4, 129.2, 144.0]
    },
    {
      name: 'Series w/o Crosshair',
      xAxis: 1,
      data: [42.1, 47.5, 150.4, 42.2, 64.0]
    }
  ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 250px"></div>
```